# Installer didn't detect old installed version NSIS

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I'am using NSIS to create a setup for my application and need to check if it's already installed:

```
 Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
    OutFile "MyAppInstaller.exe"
    InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\MyApp"
    InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" ""
    ShowInstDetails show
    ShowUnInstDetails show

    Function .onInit
    ; Check to see if already installed
      ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}" "UninstallString"
      IfFileExists $R0 +1 NotInstalled
      Messagebox MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_YESNO "MyApp 1.0 is already installed.Do you want to uninstall old version"   IDNO Quit
         Exec $R0
    Quit:
      Quit


    NotInstalled:
      !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY

    FunctionEnd ...
```

but nothing happened it always proceed installation and didn't detect the old installed version, did I miss something? I don't know much about NSIS scripting so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My only guess is that you are checking the wrong registry key or the returned path is quoted and/or has parameters so the file exists check fails.

Verify the path with `Messagebox mb_ok $R0` before the `IfFileExists` line and if it is empty you should try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), it might be able to give you some clues...

Comment: yes in deed , the right one is  `ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" "UninstallString"` thnak you for your time.